# Image composite/blending modes (multiply) in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics

In Photoshop (and many other computer graphics applications) there are are various ways that images/layers can be composited with their underlying background. These are sometimes called blending modes.

One blending mode in particular is multiply, which has the convenient feature that it eliminates white backgrounds from black line illustrations while properly dealing with anti-aliased edges (see the example below).

Is there a way to do this in LaTeX? I have a large number of images with a white background that need including in two documents with different coloured backgrounds. I'm looking for a quick way to remove the white background from the images without having to manually add an alpha mask to every image in Photoshop.

Normal blending mode:
[image]

Multiply blending mode:
[image]

Close up of anti-aliased edge, properly feathered:
[image]

Comment: latex isn't really the right tool but you shouldn't have to edit each by hand in an editor batch  conversion tools such as imagemagic should be able to do what you need to all thefiles, I would expect.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, yes if I have to resort to editing the images then something like ImageMacick should do the job. But it will take a bit of work to make sure anti-aliased images are handled properly (i.e., it's not as simple as just deleting the white background), which is why I was hoping for an easy solution using the original images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with [tikz blend modes](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transparency), or, as specified in comments using tools like imagemagic in batch mode (possibly turning the white background in a transparent background to make it possible to insert it anywhere):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=multiply]
  \node{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}};
  \node{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

You can also use instead `blend mode` instead of `blend group` to make it interact with the rest of the document, but the documentation states that some renderer fail to make it work properly. At least in Okular it seems to work. If you want a solution that is backend independent, you can also use `path picture` in order to copy the background to a new node:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  A
  % \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  %   \node[anchor=center] at (current page.center) {
  %     \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}
  %   };
  % \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[anchor=center] at (current page.center) {
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}


Hey I am some text, see how the image blends? Note however that according to the Tikz documentation, some renderer might fail to render this properly:

\vspace{-2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blend mode=multiply]
  % \node{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}};
  \node{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}

More safe (renderer independent), but will not work nicely with the background:

Hey I am some text, see how the image blends? Note however that according to the Tikz documentation, it

\vspace{-1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=multiply]
  % \node{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}};
  \node{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}


With a background picture:

\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=multiply]
  \node{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}};
  \node{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}

With path picture (renderer independent, but a bit more annoying to use, possibly a bit less reliable (we are drawing the background twice in the internal node), and it would not overlay with text that is outside of the picture):
\tikzset{
  %% WARNING: make sure to use "remember picture"
  absolute fill with image/.style={
    path picture={
      \node[anchor=center] at (current page.center) {
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}};
    }
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \begin{scope}[transparency group]
    \node[absolute fill with image=example-image]{\phantom{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example.png}}};
    \begin{scope}[blend mode=multiply]
      \node{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example.png}};
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this gets incredibly close to what I want to achieve. The missing ingredient is that this seems to blend two TikZ nodes, whereas I want to blend one image with the document's background colour. A workaround is obviously to create a second dummy node the same colour as the background and the same size as the image, but I wonder if there's a better solution?

Comment: You can use tikz to create the background: `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put (0pt, -\paperheight) {\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}}`

Comment: @Ubiquitous You should read the section on this in the manual if you plan to use this. The problem with blending in Ti*k*Z is that the different modes don't work in all viewers, so what you see in your PDF viewer may not be what I see in mine or what prints.

Comment: @Ubiquitous see my edit. Other trick are also possible using path picture if your render is failing.

Comment: @cfr @Ubiquitous I added a solution to also make it work in a render independent way using `path picture` to copy the background inside the first node.

Comment: My use case is a slide presentation that will be displayed from my own laptop, so I have the luxury of not having to worry too much about how the slides will render in arbitrary viewers. Now I can write `\newcommand{\includegraphicsMultiply}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[blend mode=multiply]\node{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};\end{tikzpicture}}` and simply replace the relevant `includegraphics` commands with `includegraphicsMultiply` in the document, which is exactly the kind of easy solution I wanted. Thanks! If ever I need to go back it will be a simple matter of redefining `includegraphicsMultiply`.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Cool then! Out of curiosity, why don't you produce directly the images as png with transparency? It would achieve a result similar to the one you showed.

Comment: @tobiasBora I am using a lot of externally generated images in my lectures (e.g., figures from other researchers or from research papers). Depending on the source and how well the image was encoded, it might have anti-aliasing, blurry edges, or compression artefacts that all make manually adding transparency more complicated than simply "deleting the white part". But I also want slides with a light grey background to reduce the strain of staring at bright LCD screens for two hours during a dark winter afternoon.

Comment: @Ubiquitous I see, make sense. Multiplication is indeed a cool idea if you work mostly with black and white pictures.